# How to use isnull in where clause of SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a bit valued column that has entries 0, 1, NULL.

I need to show all entries where

```
bcode = 0
```

Since default 0 is not set for the column hence I need to handle the nulls.

To get all the entries that have null and 0 entry in the bit column I write below query

```
select code 
from tbl_sample 
where (bcode = 0 or bcode is null)
```

I'm not sure if this will returns both 0s and NULLs. But if it does to simply the above query will the below query work or will it result to wrong output?

```
select code 
from tbl_sample 
where isnull(bcode, 0) = 0
```

or

```
select code 
from tbl_sample 
where isnull(bcode, '') = 0
```

What is the right way?

Comment: You *can* do that, but it's not performant. Stick to `bcode=0 OR bcode IS NULL`.

Comment: Generally, it's recommended to do not use non-standard functions when not required. I agree your query with OR should be prefered, but even if you want to avoid that, better use COALESCE than ISNULL because COALESCE is a standard function.

Comment: Don't change the query. Trying to filter on function results prevents the database from using indexes. The query engine will have to scan the entire table to calculate the function result before it filters the rows. That means the engine will have to scan all 1M rows even if only just 100  have NULL or 0 in `bcode`

Comment: @JonasMetzler this has nothing to do with non-standard functions - no database is compliant with the SQL standard beyond the most basic level. `COALESCE` is as bad as `ISNULL` and forces a full table scan

Comment: If you would read my comment more precise, you would notice I agree that both COALESCE and ISNULL should not be used in this case.

Comment: *"
Generally, it's recommended to do not use non-standard functions when not required"* I disagree with this, @JonasMetzler , if you have better/alternative tools it can be better to use them. Many people use `CAST` over `CONVERT` in SQL Server because of this logic, but then have difficultly converting values (to date and time values) and `CAST` doesn't support styles. `ISNULL` and `COALESCE` are also *not* the same, one uses data type precedence, the other does not.

Comment: "if you have better/alternative tools it can be better to use them" -> That's just a definition for "required", that's because I wrote "if not required".

Comment: That's not the definition of required, @JonasMetzler . ANSI-SQL syntax <> Recommended. Use the syntax appropriate for the dialect you are using. Like the example I used, I almost exclusively use `CONVERT`, even when I don't need a style. I know all too well that if I ever need to more to a different DB<S I'm going to have to rewrite a lot of it anyway, so there's really no benefit to "recommend" ANSI-SQL over T-SQL.

Comment: Well, I will not continue this opinionated discussion. I'm sure people understand what my comment means.

Answer (score 1):

As I mention in the comments, using the syntax you already have is the correct call here. Though you *could* use `ISNULL` or `COALESCE`, that would make the query non-SARGable, which would mean that any indexes you have on the table could not be used to help the RDBMS filter to the rows you want, which could mean the query is *significantly* slower.

> Since default 0 is not set for the column

Honestly, this sounds like that you *should* be changing your column's definition to `bcode bit NOT NULL` (I assume `bit` as it can only be `0` and `1`) and then create a `DEFAULT` `CONSTRAINT`:

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
ADD CONSTRAINT DF_YourTable_Bcode DEFAULT 0 FOR Bcode;
```

If you're on the bleeding edge of SQL Server though (2022+) you could use `IS DISTINCT FROM` (again, assuming your statement that the column can only have `1`, `0` and `NULL` is true and/or `bcode` is a `bit`):

```sql
SELECT code
FROM dbo.YourTable
WHERE BCode IS DISTINCT FROM 1;
```

Comment: So setting a default value for the column is the best way to avoid null handling.

Comment: I didn't say that, @JenK . I said that in *your* scenario it seems that you shouldn't be allowed `NULL` values, and likely should also be using a `DEFAULT` value.